# Is lysozyme present in the lysosome?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology

Is lysozyme present in the lysosome? I cannot find anything about this in the literature.

Comment: @infinite if you have got your answer, feel free to self answer it. Self answer are always appreciated and it also help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lysozyme is not a lysosomal protease and the pH optima is too basic for the function in the lysosome we can conclude that lysozyme is not present in lysosome.

Comment: This is not the type of answer required on this site. Lysozyme is either present in or absent from lysosomes. An acceptable answer would refer to papers in which the enzyme was assayed in different cell compartments. Statements that it is not a protease (we know that) and that it has a basic pH optimum ( what, precisely?) do not allow us to conclude anything about its subcellular location.